# Google Analytics in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, google-analytics

Does magento 1.9.0.1 have the old Google analytics or the new universal analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Universal Analytics was introduced in Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

Magento CE 1.9.0.1 supports the "old" analytics. You would need a custom module or an extension to use Universal Analytics with 1.9.0.1.

[This plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-universal-analytics-1.html) is quite popular. NOTE: I didn't test it myself...

Comment: Thanks... that's what i needed to know... is there a good and best one?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have edited my answer with a link to a (free) plugin that is available via Magento Connect

Comment: I would try this module which has all the enhanced ecommerce features -: https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html